# Display a title in the Content

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing a report in Latex, I am using Latexila. 
I wonder how can I display a section (defined by `\chapter*{Introduction}`) 
in my able of contents. In fact, the table of content doesn't show (Introduction) when I compile and I execute the PDF.
Any Idea?

Comment: Write `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}` after the `\chapter*{Introduction}` command.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for you to use `\chapter*` instead of `\chapter`?

Comment: @campa Yeah, I have to repect the protocol of (writing reports ) in my school. 
Introduction, abstract & acknowledgments must not be numeroted.

Thanks to all