# Font by default latex

Tags: fonts

I'm using a template that I can't/shouldn't modify. This template forces a font which is not the normal font of latex, how can I restaure the automatic font (I think which is Serif by default)

The template:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}


\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{sffamily}
  \begin{center}

    % Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
    % only works if a paragraph has started.
    %\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{img1.JPG}~\\[1.5cm]

    \textsc{\LARGE HEC}\\[2cm]

    \textsc{\Large INTERNSHIP'S REPORT 2nd YEAR}\\[5cm]

    % Title
    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    { \huge \bfseries System recommendations of Routes-
Experimentation In a dynamic research project\\[0.4cm] } 

\HRule \\[8cm]
    %\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{img2.JPG}
    Abstract
This document aims to give an overview of the internship I carried out from June 15 to September 11 2015 in xxxxx, in order to complete my 2nd year of engineering at xxxx.
KEYWORDS: Java, Maven, Iinerary, Recommendation, Context, Capsule, Collector, Application

    % Author and supervisor
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{flushleft} \large 
        xxxx \textsc{xxxxx}\\
        Promo 2016\\
      \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{Supervisor :} Mme. \textsc{xxxxx}\\
        %\emph{Chef d'équipe : } M. Chef \textsc{D’Équipe}
      \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}

    \vfill

    % Bottom of the page
    %{\large 1\ier{} Juillet 2013 — 30 Août 2013}

  \end{center}
  \end{sffamily}
\end{titlepage}





%\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
```

Comment: Just remove `\usepackage{libertine}`.

Comment: The sans serif in the titlepage comes from the `sffamily` environment.

Comment: I have removed the [`biblatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/biblatex/info) tag. [Another question of yours](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262482/35864) was also tagged `biblatex` originally, even though it had nothing to do with `biblatex` (`biblatex` is a bibliography package, neither do you load it, no is your question remotely about bibliographies). Please be a bit more careful with tagging in the future.

Comment: And add  `\usepackage{lmodern}` since its loads `T1` font encoding. By the way, there is no ‘normal’  font in LaTeX. There is a default font (Computer Modern), that most people aren't able to change. It is as though you said Times is the normal font for a M* Office document.

Comment: If you can't modify the template, then you clearly can't change the font either.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Is there such an environment? I can never remember which are also environments and which not, but I can't find one in `tex/latex/base/*` - only the switch.

Comment: @cfr Not really: [Do fontsize environments exist?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258277)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks. That's what I thought....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is contradictory in itself.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an old question but it is still missing a formal answer which I'd like to provide. As already mentioned in the comments, there are two commands affecting the choice of fonts:

1. `\usepackage{libertine}`
2. `\begin{sffamily}`...`\end{sffamily}`

Searching on the internet will reveal that the `libertine` package "pro­vides the Lib­er­tine and Bi­olinum fonts in both Type 1 and OTF styles, to­gether with sup­port macros for their use" as can be read here: https://ctan.org/pkg/libertine

You should use the `lmodern` package instead as the Latin Modern family successes the Computer Modern family (the latter being the default font family in LaTeX).

The `sffamily` "environment" sets every font in it (and all text after it because it is not an environment) to sans serif. You have to remove the `sffamily` command / "environment" if you want serif font.

Comment: Are you really referring to me or shouldn't you comment on Sino's question as he uses the ```sffamily``` "environment"?

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you. I will adopt your proposal.